# What gem should I use in order to have all the translations in the DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, globalize3

I've played a bit with globalize and rails 3, but from what I'm able to tell, globalize only works for ActiveRecord instances. I'd also like to be able to have the translations for other static pages in the database ( say for example header,footer, company details etc. ). Is this possible to do with globalize? If not, please recommend a gem that I should use.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this using [i18n-active_record](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to translate static page parts - you may create a new model (with globalize translations) and use it for storing static content (or just put your translations into config/locales folder)

Comment: If I put the translations in the locales, how will I be able to access them from the database?

Comment: There is no way to access locales from the database. If you want to edit localized text directly from site - just create a new model for static content